# stackmob addon for heroku

Tags: heroku, add-on, stackmob

We're looking to build out our mobile app using Stackmob and Heroku for backend.

There is a Heroku Addon that enables a developer to control the app server-side logic using Rails.

There is not much documentation available on this addon nor are there examples.

There is a fair bit of media coverage on the add-on but no clear implementation and use-case path.

If any one in the community has some insight, we and other developers would sure benefit from hearing more.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the StackMob Heroku add-on is discontinued. You can still sign up for StackMob directly on the [StackMob](https://www.stackmob.com/) site and use in your Heroku apps. They have multiple getting-started guides, including [for Ruby](https://www.stackmob.com/devcenter/docs/Getting-Started%3a-Ruby), if that's what you use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the platform evangelist for StackMob.

friism is correct,  we recently discontinued the StackMob Heroku add-on. (basically a way to provision an account and get up and running a little quicker on Heroku with StackMob)

This change won't prevent you from using StackMob on the Heroku platform.